# HERE Maps API JS : How to change the date format in incident popup?

Tags: javascript, date, localization, here-api

Even if layers and UI have been created with french language :
var defaultLayers = platform.createDefaultLayers({lg : 'fre'});
var ui = H.ui.UI.createDefault(map, defaultLayers,'fr-FR');

dates in layer incidents on popup are displayed in english format :
It's like mm/dd/yyyy and I would like dd/mm/yyyy

How can I do it with here api javascript 3 ?
Thanks

PS : API reference link : https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/3.1.30.3/api_reference/index.html

Answer (score 0):

traffic API doesn't provide any lang-specific parameters. you can develop your own custom info bubble-like in this example:

https://tcs.ext.here.com/examples/v3.1/traffic_viewer

Comment: Thanks we success to integrate it with this workaround